# React native : Passing HTML string to component is displaying as text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-text

I have react native component (For Eg: myComponent) which has the below code to display text from this.props.text. This text props is defined as string in myComponent.

```
<Text size='large'
            style={styles.text}
            textId={this.props.text}
            values={this.props.values}>
          {this.props.text}
 </Text>
```

When I give text as below by sending an action, It is displaying the the text as String.But I am expecting component to display as blue highlighted Link

```
yield put(myComponent.displayAction(displayType,"<Text suppressHighlighting={false} style={{backgroundColor: 'white', textDecorationLine: 'underline', color: 'blue'}} onPress={() => null}>Link</Text>}")
```

If i directly hardcode the string in myComponent, It is displaying the Link where we can perform onclick.

```
<Text size='large'
        style={styles.text}
        textId={this.props.text}
        values={this.props.values}>
      //{this.props.text} => removed this and hardcoded the string below
      "<Text suppressHighlighting={false} style={{backgroundColor: 'white', textDecorationLine: 'underline', color: 'blue'}} onPress={() => null}>Link</Text>}"
```

Any help to display this as Link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a string with JSX in it as an element. In your hardcoded example, the compiler is treating it as an element, and ignoring the quotes.

Changing the `text` prop to be an element rather than a string, and then passing that element to `displayAction` instead, should work.

Alternatively, you can have the `text` prop contain the text instead of the element, and display it as so:

```
<Text suppressHighlighting={false} style={{backgroundColor: 'white', textDecorationLine: 'underline', color: 'blue'}} onPress={() => null}>{this.props.text}</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks. If i go for  below code,  How to handle the onPress from my class and not from the component?      <Text suppressHighlighting={false} style={{backgroundColor: 'white', textDecorationLine: 'underline', color: 'blue'}} onPress={() => null}>{this.props.text}</Text>,

Comment: @Tutu You can pass an `onPress` handler in the props too.